# Autosizer stretches width fully on browser resize on Internet Explorer

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using autosizer with

```
<div width=20% /><div flex='1'><Autosizer></div><div with=20% />
```

but it seems like whenever I resize, Autosizer stretches 100% to its right side

and it calculates too big width and it overlaps the last

```
 <div with=20% />
```

The problem is only happening on Internet Explorer and I cannot find any solution to it.

Comment: I've resolved it by not using flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `flex=1` is as an attribute, but assuming you're referring to a style `flex: 1` - that's shorthand for telling the div that it can grow to fill its container. `flex: 0` or `flex-grow: 0` would tell it not to grow.

It looks to me like `AutoSizer` is behaving as expected given its parents. :)